# Bitcoin node gets stuck on a stale tip

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

o7

I'm having a issue with my node. I'm running it on a 2017 mba, and randomly it'll get stuck on a stale tip and apparently can't find the active branch, as it'll try for hours until manually restarted. The most i can figure out is it fails to connect to a peer and then just stops trying? Relevant logs are attached below system info.

Bitcoin core version: `Bitcoin Core version v23.0`

Config:

```
## General
server=1
txindex=1
blockfilterindex=1
daemonwait=1
mempoolexpiry=24
disablewallet=1
sysperms=1
datadir=/run/media/<user>/Chain/bitcoin
shrinkdebugfile=1

## Services
peerbloomfilters=1
peerblockfilters=1

zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000

## Networking
port=8333
rpcuser=mempool
rpcpassword=mempool
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rest=1
listen=1
discover=1
maxconnections=25
whitelist=download@127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24
### Tor
listenonion=1
onion=127.0.0.1:9050

## Tor Seeds
addnode=kpgvmscirrdqpekbqjsvw5teanhatztpp2gl6eee4zkowvwfxwenqaid.onion
addnode=bnx4povtqynvwnui5oqm5xcxqvat3j7yzgn6mqciuyszqawhuayvyaid.onion:8333
addnode=qxkgr5u4rmwme5jticjuuqrecw5vfc5thcqdxvbffwbqgqkdin7s7vid.onion
```

System info:
OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64
Host: MacBookAir7,2 1.0
Kernel: 5.18.12-zen1-1-zen
Shell: bash 5.1.16
CPU: Intel i5-5350U (4) @ 2.900GHz

Relevant logs:

```
2022-07-27T12:16:11Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000004d531a2a6bda3200d27f01e1788fa8542eecd337c9759 height=746776 version=0x2222a000 log2_work=93.648170 tx=752013680 date='2022-07-27T12:15:46Z' progress=1.000000 cache=44.8MiB(342049txo)
2022-07-27T12:17:59Z Socks5() connect to z35xbo2q2mclub2pfljc6q4czxuvbivohmuoi3jrw5yukzqb635li2id.onion:8333 failed: host unreachable // first connection failure
2022-07-27T12:18:14Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=746776, peer=281 (block-relay-only)
// ..normal logs...
2022-07-27T12:59:53Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=746783, peer=307 (block-relay-only)
2022-07-27T13:02:14Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000089e9978c6b5e69d0d02109ad3e418ec096ce03d3292b0 height=746784 version=0x20800004 log2_work=93.648258 tx=752022658 date='2022-07-27T13:00:22Z' progress=1.000000 cache=52.2MiB(380114txo) // Seems to die here, as this was the height i found it at when i restarted at block 746826
2022-07-27T13:24:16Z Disconnecting outbound peer 9 for old chain, best known block = 000000000000000000098d0c86665071e838f3483d582c0af7a16ef07745020e
2022-07-27T13:24:16Z Disconnecting outbound peer 1 for old chain, best known block = 000000000000000000098d0c86665071e838f3483d582c0af7a16ef07745020e
2022-07-27T13:24:16Z Disconnecting outbound peer 17 for old chain, best known block = 000000000000000000098d0c86665071e838f3483d582c0af7a16ef07745020e
2022-07-27T13:24:16Z Disconnecting outbound peer 16 for old chain, best known block = 000000000000000000098d0c86665071e838f3483d582c0af7a16ef07745020e
2022-07-27T13:36:10Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2036 seconds ago)
2022-07-27T13:46:40Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2666 seconds ago)
2022-07-27T13:57:10Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 3296 seconds ago)
2022-07-27T14:07:40Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 3926 seconds ago)
2022-07-27T14:18:10Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 4556 seconds ago)
// ...continues...
2022-07-27T17:27:10Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 15896 seconds ago)
```

Edit: Also seems to hang on exit, and it even logs stale tip messages. `pkill -9` doesnt kill it either, only a reboot will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue seems to have been my vpn, after disabling it my node stopped getting stuck.